# Optimizing slow UNION ALL query across multiple DBs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

```
SELECT 'ULTIPRO_MDUSG0002' AS dbname
           ,max(EventDate)
FROM [ULTIPRO_MDUSG0002].DBO.vw_rbsUserLoginHistorywhere SourceType = 
'MOBILE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ULTIPRO_MDUSG0027' AS dbname
           ,max(EventDate)
FROM [ULTIPRO_MDUSG0027].DBO.vw_rbsUserLoginHistorywhere SourceType =     'MOBILE'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ULTIPRO_MDUSG0028' AS dbname
               ,max(EventDate)
    FROM [ULTIPRO_MDUSG0028].DBO.vw_rbsUserLoginHistorywhere SourceType = 'MOBILE'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ULTIPRO_MDUSG0050' AS dbname
               ,max(EventDate)
    FROM [ULTIPRO_MDUSG0050].DBO.vw_rbsUserLoginHistorywhere SourceType = 'MOBILE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ULTIPRO_MDUSG0051' AS dbname
               ,max(EventDate)
FROM [ULTIPRO_MDUSG0051].DBO.vw_rbsUserLoginHistorywhere SourceType = 'MOBILE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ULTIPRO_MDUSG0071' AS dbname
               ,max(EventDate)
FROM [ULTIPRO_MDUSG0071].DBO.vw_rbsUserLoginHistorywhere SourceType = 'MOBILE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ULTIPRO_MDUSG0072' AS dbname
               ,max(EventDate)
FROM [ULTIPRO_MDUSG0072].DBO.vw_rbsUserLoginHistorywhere SourceType = 'MOBILE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ULTIPRO_MDUSG0073' AS dbname
               ,max(EventDate)
FROM [ULTIPRO_MDUSG0073].DBO.vw_rbsUserLoginHistorywhere SourceType = 'MOBILE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ULTIPRO_MDUSG0074' AS dbname
               ,max(EventDate)
FROM [ULTIPRO_MDUSG0074].DBO.vw_rbsUserLoginHistorywhere SourceType = 'MOBILE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ULTIPRO_MDUSG0075' AS dbname
               ,max(EventDate)
FROM [ULTIPRO_MDUSG0075].DBO.vw_rbsUserLoginHistorywhere SourceType = 'MOBILE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ULTIPRO_MDUSG0076' AS dbname
               ,max(EventDate)
FROM [ULTIPRO_MDUSG0076].DBO.vw_rbsUserLoginHistorywhere SourceType = 'MOBILE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ULTIPRO_MDUSG0077' AS dbname
               ,max(EventDate)
FROM [ULTIPRO_MDUSG0077].DBO.vw_rbsUserLoginHistorywhere SourceType = 'MOBILE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ULTIPRO_MDUSG0078' AS dbname
               ,max(EventDate)
FROM [ULTIPRO_MDUSG0078].DBO.vw_rbsUserLoginHistorywhere SourceType = 'MOBILE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ULTIPRO_MDUSG0079' AS dbname
               ,max(EventDate)
FROM [ULTIPRO_MDUSG0079].DBO.vw_rbsUserLoginHistorywhere SourceType = 'MOBILE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ULTIPRO_MDUSG0080' AS dbname
               ,max(EventDate)
FROM [ULTIPRO_MDUSG0080].DBO.vw_rbsUserLoginHistorywhere SourceType = 'MOBILE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ULTIPRO_MDUSG0081' AS dbname
               ,max(EventDate)
FROM [ULTIPRO_MDUSG0081].DBO.vw_rbsUserLoginHistorywhere SourceType = 'MOBILE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ULTIPRO_MDUSG0082' AS dbname
               ,max(EventDate)
FROM [ULTIPRO_MDUSG0082].DBO.vw_rbsUserLoginHistorywhere SourceType = 'MOBILE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ULTIPRO_MDUSG0084' AS dbname
               ,max(EventDate)
FROM [ULTIPRO_MDUSG0084].DBO.vw_rbsUserLoginHistorywhere SourceType = 'MOBILE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ULTIPRO_MDUSG0089' AS dbname
               ,max(EventDate)
FROM [ULTIPRO_MDUSG0089].DBO.vw_rbsUserLoginHistorywhere SourceType = 'MOBILE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ULTIPRO_MDUSG0090' AS dbname
               ,max(EventDate)
FROM [ULTIPRO_MDUSG0090].DBO.vw_rbsUserLoginHistorywhere SourceType = 'MOBILE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ULTIPRO_MDUSG0091' AS dbname
               ,max(EventDate)
FROM [ULTIPRO_MDUSG0091].DBO.vw_rbsUserLoginHistorywhere SourceType = 'MOBILE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ULTIPRO_MDUSG0096' AS dbname
               ,max(EventDate)
FROM [ULTIPRO_MDUSG0096].DBO.vw_rbsUserLoginHistorywhere SourceType = 'MOBILE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ULTIPRO_MDUSG0155' AS dbname
               ,max(EventDate)
FROM [ULTIPRO_MDUSG0155].DBO.vw_rbsUserLoginHistorywhere SourceType =     'MOBILE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ULTIPRO_MDUSG0156' AS dbname
               ,max(EventDate)    
FROM [ULTIPRO_MDUSG0156].DBO.vw_rbsUserLoginHistorywhere SourceType = 'MOBILE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ULTIPRO_MDUSG0157' AS dbname
               ,max(EventDate)
FROM [ULTIPRO_MDUSG0157].DBO.vw_rbsUserLoginHistorywhere SourceType = 'MOBILE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ULTIPRO_MDUSG0158' AS dbname
               ,max(EventDate)
FROM [ULTIPRO_MDUSG0158].DBO.vw_rbsUserLoginHistorywhere SourceType = 'MOBILE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ULTIPRO_MDUSG0159' AS dbname
               ,max(EventDate)
FROM [ULTIPRO_MDUSG0159].DBO.vw_rbsUserLoginHistorywhere SourceType = 'MOBILE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ULTIPRO_MDUSG0182' AS dbname
               ,max(EventDate)
FROM [ULTIPRO_MDUSG0182].DBO.vw_rbsUserLoginHistorywhere SourceType = 'MOBILE'
UNION
```

Comment: First you need to ask a question (how to optimize? what to further optimize? etc.). Second, please post at least one of those table structures with your indexes.

Comment: Have you got an index on event date on each table?

Comment: What you posted isn't valid sql because there is no space before the where keyword. This leads me to believe that this isn't your actual query. And without the view definition AND the table structures under it there is no chance anybody can help you here.

Comment: Create a data warehouse and ship the data to it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to create a view like this. It may increase the speed a bit by just executing queries on this source, just add the rest at the bottom of it (also need a space before the `where`)

```
CREATE VIEW AllHistory
AS

SELECT 'ULTIPRO_MDUSG0002' AS dbname
           ,max(EventDate)
FROM [ULTIPRO_MDUSG0002].DBO.vw_rbsUserLoginHistory where SourceType = 
'MOBILE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ULTIPRO_MDUSG0027' AS dbname
       ,max(EventDate)
FROM [ULTIPRO_MDUSG0027].DBO.vw_rbsUserLoginHistory where SourceType =     'MOBILE'
UNION ALL
--the rest of them here..
```

then

```
SELECT * 
FROM AllHistory
```

Comment: huh? I don't see a difference?

Comment: How would this make this any faster?